# budgie-welcome displays blanks

Tags: budgie

I was getting blank budgie-welcome after upgrading from Budgie on 21.10. Trying one thing and another, it told me to

```
snap install ubuntu-budgie-welcome
```

Then, it told me it can only do that outside the sandboxes for snaps:

```
 sudo snap install ubuntu-budgie-welcome
error: This revision of snap "ubuntu-budgie-welcome" was published using
       classic confinement and thus may perform arbitrary system changes
       outside of the security sandbox that snaps are usually confined to,
       which may put your system at risk.

       If you understand and want to proceed repeat the command including
       --classic.
```

with or without classic, it still gave me an empty box, with a budgie-welcome header.

Am I missing anything without the welcome?

Answer (score 0):

Clear your mime cache.

rm ~/.local/share/mime/mime.cache

Personal experience of just having this issue and finding this.
https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/ubuntu-budgie-welcome-probleme-mit-snap/